# How to initialize a SimpleNamespace from a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm sure this must be simple, but I could not find the answer.

I have a dictionary like:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b':2}
```

I'd like to access that via dot notation, like: `d.a`

The [`SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html) is designed for this, but I cannot just pass the dict into the SimpleNamespace constructor. 
I get the error: `TypeError: no positional arguments expected`

How do I initialize the SimpleNamespace from a dictionary?

Comment: recursive solutions: [Creating a namespace with a dict of dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490856/creating-a-namespace-with-a-dict-of-dicts) and [How to convert a nested python dictionary into a simple namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66208077/how-to-convert-a-nested-python-dictionary-into-a-simple-namespace)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Pass in the dictionary using the [`**kwargs` call syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to unpack your dictionary into separate arguments:

```
SimpleNamespace(**d)
```

This applies each key-value pair in `d` as a separate keyword argument.

Conversely, the closely related [`**kwargs` parameter definition](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) in the `__init__` method of the class definition [shown in the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) captures all keyword arguments passed to the class into a single dictionary again.

Demo:

```
>>> from types import SimpleNamespace
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b':2}
>>> sn = SimpleNamespace(**d)
>>> sn
namespace(a=1, b=2)
>>> sn.a
1
```