# Creating a namespace with a dict of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Currently I am using `json` to save a dict to a config file. I load this to turn it into a `dict` then turn it into a `SimpleNamespace` because I prefer dot notation to access the settings. To do this, I load it as in this example:

```
import json
from types import SimpleNamespace
SETTINGS = json.load(open("config.json", 'r'))
SETTINGS = SimpleNamespace(**SETTINGS)
```

However, as I am currently loading the `dict` into a `SimpleNamespace` it is not loading the sub dicts within the config file. So for example if I do:

```
SETTINGS.server_info.port
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'port'
```

I was wondering how I load all dicts into the namespace as name spaces so that I am able to use dot notation all the way down the dictionary.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is not necessary to recursively apply the transformation to the data returned by `json.load`.  You can simply ask `json.load` to return `SimpleNamespace` instances instead of dictionaries by providing an `object_hook` method to the `json.load` call.  This method "will be called with the result of every JSON object decoded and its return value will be used in place of the given `dict`." (from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders)).

The simplest `object_hook` might look like:

```
def dict_to_sns(d):
    return SimpleNamespace(**d)
```

For example, given the following input:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "foo": {
      "number": 4,
      "size": "large"
    },
    "bar": {
      "color": "orange",
      "widgets": [
        "gizmo",
        "gadget",
        "thing"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

We can do the following:

```
>>> import json
>>> from types import SimpleNamespace
>>> def dict_to_sns(d):
...     return SimpleNamespace(**d)
... 
>>> with open('settings.json') as fd:
...     data = json.load(fd, object_hook=dict_to_sns)
... 
>>> data
namespace(settings=namespace(bar=namespace(color='orange', widgets=['gizmo', 'gadget', 'thing']), foo=namespace(number=4, size='large')))
>>> data.settings.foo
namespace(number=4, size='large')
>>> data.settings.foo.number
4
>>> data.settings.bar.widgets
['gizmo', 'gadget', 'thing']
```

Answer (score 13):

You'll have to recursively apply the `SimpleNamespace` class to nested dictionaries; I prefer to use [`@functools.singledispatch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) for such cases:

```
from functools import singledispatch
from types import SimpleNamespace

@singledispatch
def wrap_namespace(ob):
    return ob

@wrap_namespace.register(dict)
def _wrap_dict(ob):
    return SimpleNamespace(**{k: wrap_namespace(v) for k, v in ob.items()})

@wrap_namespace.register(list)
def _wrap_list(ob):
    return [wrap_namespace(v) for v in ob]
```

then use this as:

```
with open('config.json') as settings_file:
    SETTINGS = wrap_namespace(json.load(settings_file))
```

Demo:

```
>>> SETTINGS = wrap_namespace({'foo': 'bar', 'ham': {'spam': 'eggs', 'monty': [{'name': 'Eric Idle'}]}})
>>> SETTINGS.foo
'bar'
>>> SETTINGS.ham.monty[0].name
'Eric Idle'
```

Comment: **See also:** [functools.singledispatchmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24602374/42223)