# How to initialize a dict from a SimpleNamespace?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It has been asked: [How to initialize a SimpleNamespace from a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296097/how-to-initialize-a-simplenamespace-from-a-dict)

My question is for the opposite direction. How to initialize a dict from a SimpleNamespace?

Comment: That is what `vars()` builtin function is for.

Comment: I can't mark the answer as correct, if you place it here. :)

Comment: it's really weird that `dict(sn)` fails. See example and error: `dict(args)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brando/anaconda3/envs/automl-meta-learning/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-1bf3c62db268>", line 1, in <module>
    dict(args)
TypeError: 'types.SimpleNamespace' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

sn = SimpleNamespace(a=1, b=2, c=3)

vars(sn)
# returns {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

sn.__dict__
# also returns {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: it's really weird that `dict(sn)` fails. See example and error: `dict(args)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brando/anaconda3/envs/automl-meta-learning/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-1bf3c62db268>", line 1, in <module>
    dict(args)
TypeError: 'types.SimpleNamespace' object is not iterable`

Comment: Try to do that for 
```
sn = SimpleNamespace(hetero_list=['aa', SimpleNamespace(y='ll')] )
```

It wont work

Comment: It's important for people to understand, this doesn't *convert to a `dict`*, this merely **retrieves the instance namespace**

Answer (score 3):

The straightway **dict** wont work for heterogeneous lists.

```py
import json

sn = SimpleNamespace(hetero_list=['aa', SimpleNamespace(y='ll')] )
json.loads(json.dumps(sn, default=lambda s: vars(s)))
```

This is the only way to get back the dict.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an issue where I had a complex SimpleNamespace with SimpleNamespace within it, so I needed a recursive way to convert it into a dictionary. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/sungitly/3f75cb297572dace2937?permalink_comment_id=3172936#gistcomment-3172936) was super helpful, since it converts the SimpleNamespace recursively.

```
def obj_to_dict(obj):
if type(obj) is dict:
    res = {}
    for k, v in obj.items():
        res[k] = obj_to_dict(v)
    return res
elif type(obj) is list:
    return [obj_to_dict(item) for item in obj]
elif type(obj) is SimpleNamespace:
    return obj_to_dict(vars(obj))
else:
    return obj
```